# Do I need to change "OS Optimized defaults" to install Ubuntu as my only OS?

Tags: uefi, lenovo, ssd, configuration, ideapad

in thinking about **replacing** my windows 10 (default) installation with Ubuntu 20.04.

My machine is a Lenovo ideapad 330s-15IKB (with a 500GB M.2 Nvme SSD installed instead of the normal Intel Optane).

After looking in different forums, question, videos and Lenovo documents, I still have doubts about whether I will need to set any special UEFI configuration or not.

As I mentioned before, Ubuntu will be **my only OS**, not part of a dual boot. So my question remains on which **pre-configurations** are going to be necessary to install Ubuntu on my machine.

PD: I've already tried Ubuntu without installing (with my flashed USB) and everything works correctly (even better than I expected), so maybe that's a good sign.

Answer (score 0):

You probably won't notice any difference in loading the OS Optimized Defaults and it won't make any difference during installation. There is one consideration about the UEFI.  From the [Ideapad 330s-151K manual](https://download.lenovo.com/consumer/mobiles_pub/330s-14ikb_330s-14ikbx_330s-15ikb_330s-15ikbx_ug_en_201803.pdf)

```
How can I change the boot mode? (on select models)
There are two boot modes: UEFI and Legacy Support. To change the boot mode, start the BIOS
setup utility and set boot mode to UEFI or Legacy Support on the boot menu.
When do I need to change the boot mode? (on select models)
The default boot mode for your computer is UEFI mode. If you need to install a legacy Windows
operating system on your computer, you must change the boot mode to Legacy Support. The
legacy Windows operating system cannot be installed if you don't change the boot mode.
```

I would not select UEFI even though you're not planning to keep Windows 10. I'd go with the Legacy setting and avoid UEFI because I'm not convinced of its worth.

Good luck.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I got surprised when you told me not to boot in UEFI mode as I had understood that Ubuntu supports both UEFI mode and Secure Boot, which is usually not recommended by the community. Is there any special reason for this "discrepancy"?

Comment: for a linux laptop, I don't think you need UEFI.  You'll have to create a partition to boot from UEFI.  Since you're not planning a dual boot system, nor need more than 4 primary partitions, I think that the BIOS methods will suffice using MBR (Master Boot Record).

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Linux

Comment: So let me see if I understand... In my case it is recommended to install Ubuntu 20.04 in Legacy mode as it will be more compatible, less problematic and simpler, and I won't be missing anything from UEFI (since you have to have a 2TB disk to really feel the difference).

Comment: Please correct me if I'm wrong as I'm here to learn.

Comment: But I have another question, wouldn't it be easier to install it in UEFI mode since Ubuntu will automatically make the partitions it needs?

Comment: I would also take a look at the UEFI article in Wikipedia before making a final decision. The standard has changed a few times, and I have had troubles with maintaining UEFI with Windows 8.x and Ubuntu to the point that I don't make dual boot configurations any more.

Comment: But in your case, maybe keeping UEFI may provide future value.